# Oracle -> oci_define_by_name in sqlsrv [php]

Tags: php, sql-server, oracle, odbc, sqlsrv

What is the equivalent in SQLSRV for the following function from ORACLE extention `oci_define_by_name`?

Docs: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.oci-define-by-name.php

How can I translate this (oracle php) in sqlsrv?

```
 if ( isset( $_GET['Refdti'] ) ) 
  {
    $Refdti  = $_GET['Refdti'];
  }

  $ora_stmt = oci_parse($ora_connect, $request);
  if ( ! $ora_stmt ) 
  {
    $retour = array('success' => false, 'msg' => 'Problem oci_parse requete='.$request);
    oci_close($ora_connect);
    return;
  }
  oci_define_by_name($ora_stmt, 'REFDTI'   , $refdti);
```

Comment: If you look at the [SQL Server prepare](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php), the parameters are part of the call - `array $params`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that PHP Driver for SQL Server (`sqlsrv` extension) supports exact equivalent of `oci_define_by_name()` function (to associate a PHP variable with a column for query fetches). Probably the appropriate approach is to use `sqlsrv_fetch_array()` function to retrieve the next row of data. Note, that you can use `sqlsrv_query()` to prepare and execute a statement, because (as is mentioned in the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/php/sqlsrv-query?view=sql-server-ver15#remarks)) this *function is well-suited for one-time queries and should be the default choice to execute queries unless special circumstances apply*.

Oracle example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['Refdti'])) {
    $Refdti = $_GET['Refdti'];
}

...
$ora_stmt = oci_parse($ora_connect, $request);
if (!$ora_stmt ) {
    $retour = array('success' => false, 'msg' => 'Problem oci_parse requete='.$request);
    oci_close($ora_connect);
    return;
}
oci_define_by_name($ora_stmt, 'REFDTI' , $refdti);
oci_execute($stid);

while (oci_fetch($ora_stmt)) {
    echo $refdti."\n";
}  

...
?>
```

SQL Server example:

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['Refdti'])) {
    $Refdti = $_GET['Refdti'];
}

...
$ms_stmt = sqlsrv_query($ms_connect, $request);
if ($ms_stmt === false ) {
    $retour = array('success' => false, 'msg' => 'Problem sqlsrv_query requete='.$request);
    sqlsrv_close($ms_connect);
    return;
}

while ($row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($ms_stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC)) {
    echo $row["REFDTI"]."\n";
}

...
?>
```

Comment: thanks of all rep I understand, I will try it this week when I have time and post what I have do.This is clear